# Mysterious 403 errors on images with proper permissions

Tags: images, 403-forbidden

Recently I have been trying to install a forum on my website. At first I was having an issue with the forums alone but then I noticed it was occurring elsewhere on my website as well.

When I have added images, they return in a 403 error. The images are there but they refuse to show up.

I have tried it with multiple permissions numbers but every time I get the same result. After further inquiry, I discovered that some images were working. Here are a couple of examples:

[Working, 0644 Permissions](http://puppier.net/fednet/images/bug.png)

[Not Working, 0644 Permissions](http://puppier.net/fednet/images/add.png)

If you go to the directory that contains both of those images you will also see that no images show up in the directory.

I do not know what's going on. In other parts of the website, images with full 777 permissions are resulting in 403 errors. I have talked with the hosting service but they have just directed me to change permissions, which I have done.

Comment: I get a 403 for both those images you linked to. What are the permissions for all the folders in your root directory and sub folders? Then what are the permissions of the images. And what about your .htaccess file is it restricting access to any images?

Comment: Something is strange with your site if I browse the folder I see no images if I go down a level and back up I then see all your images and can click on them and they appear.

Comment: Ah. You see the problem. Well here we go: public_html: 755, /fednet/: 755, /images/: 755 and the images are listed above. Both are 0644.

Comment: Do the images display properly in the forum? Is there anything in your .htaccess? Maybe something to do with hot linking... Directory browsing shouldn't be allowed so in your htaccess file set `Options -Indexes`

Comment: Since the image problem occurs when browsing folders and accessing the images directly it's most likely a configuration problem with the web server (apache) or .htaccess

Comment: Have you fixed this...? Both those images work OK for me. I can also view the directory listing of all the images, and the images I've tried all work OK.

Comment: I do have hot linking prevention. I'll look at that. It seems as if it is working for those images now although it is not working for other images.

Comment: It did turn out to be hotlink protection! (That is the second time it has messed me up) Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RobertRose can you add an answer for anyone else who has the same problem?